# Am I required to report an incident that isn't specifically mentioned in 49 CFR 830?

Tags: faa-regulations, incidents, ntsb

I have read an understand NTSB Part 830, and know that IMMEDIATE notification to the NTSB is required for aircraft accidents and the listed serious incidents. My question is, is there a requirement to notify the NTSB or FAA of an incident that is not listed in part 830? This is not a question about accident reporting, but specifically incident reporting for incidents that are not listed in the regulation.

Possible scenario: While landing at an uncontrolled field, the airplane loses directional control and departs the runway into the grass and the airplane did not receive substantial damage nor was there a serious injury or death.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I believe your question has already been answered, but if not then please feel free to edit it to add more details about what you need that isn't covered in the other question. You might also find the [tour] is helpful if you're new to the site.

Comment: The other question doesn't reference notification for incidents that are not listed in the regulations, which is what this question is about.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm just not sure I understand how you could be required to report something if there's no regulation. Your insurer or flying club might want to know, of course. I'm not trying to be difficult, I just don't know how to answer the question of how to report something when there's no requirement to report it. Maybe [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/184/62) helps?

Comment: Maybe there is a secret regulation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of part 91 regulations that require 'general' incident reporting, but only if the FAA or ATC requests it.

[14 CFR 91.3(c)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_13) says that if a pilot exercised emergency authority to deviate from part 91 rules then the FAA can ask for a report:

> (b) In an in-flight emergency requiring immediate action, the pilot in
> command may deviate from any rule of this part to the extent required
> to meet that emergency.
>
> (c) Each pilot in command who deviates from a rule under paragraph (b)
> of this section shall, upon the request of the Administrator, send a
> written report of that deviation to the Administrator.

[91.123(d)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1123) says that ATC can ask for a report if they gave a pilot emergency priority, even if the pilot didn't deviate from any rules:

> (d) Each pilot in command who (though not deviating from a rule of
> this subpart) is given priority by ATC in an emergency, shall submit a
> detailed report of that emergency within 48 hours to the manager of
> that ATC facility, if requested by ATC.

There are also regulations for charters ([135.415](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=eb6193190e9bb6f10aa8626d34e3f466&mc=true&node=pt14.3.135&rgn=div5#se14.3.135_1415)) and airlines ([121.703](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=eb6193190e9bb6f10aa8626d34e3f466&mc=true&node=sp14.3.121.v&rgn=div6#se14.3.121_1703)) that have a long list of "service difficulties" that must be reported, including in-flight fires, brake failures and others. And there are likely non-FAA regulations on things like HAZMAT incidents.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. You do not *have* to report it to the NTSB or FAA. But, it depends on the circumstances and amount of damage. Though, you can and probably should file a NASA report, anyway. This will contribute to statistical analysis of accidents for future accident prevention and safety.